# List manager Contact list was not saved in Sitecore 9.0.1

Tags: list-manager

While saving the contact using List Manager, we got contact saved successfully with message "The contact has been added to the list, and will be available after indexing.".

But it was not display in the list and below error was captured in logs:

```
Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbSearchUnavailableException Message: The HTTP response was not successful: InternalServerError Source: Sitecore.XConnect.Client    at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.SearchWebApiClient.<Search>d__9`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Operations.SearchOperationInvoker.<Execute>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.SearchHelpers.<ExecuteSearch>d__6`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.SearchDefinition`1.<Execute>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.AsyncSearchHitEnumerator`1.<Create>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.AsyncEntityQueryProvider.<ExecuteAsync>d__8`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.AsyncEntityQueryProvider.<ExecuteAsync>d__7`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Sitecore.ListManagement.XConnect.ContactsOperationIndexingState.IsFinished(String syncToken)    at Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent.CheckIndexing(ListOperation listOperation)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is possibly because of SolrCore connection issue.
You can troubleshoot this by following the steps below

1. Navigate to the C:\inetpub\wwwroot\siteinstance.xConnect\App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config (sc901 is the name of the site)

   `<add name="solrCore" connectionString="https://localhost:8983/solr/sc901_xdb" />`
2. Check the if the code listed in the SolrCore exisits and accessible via solr dashboard.You can check this by navigating to https://localhost:8983/solr/#/ and also make sure C:(where ever the solr host files are located)\solr-6.6.2\server\solr contains the same 'sc901_xdb' folder.
3. If it does not exists, you can create **xDB** and **xdb_rebuild** cores by using the link https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-search-indexer/rebuild-index/rebuild-solr-index.html#create-a-rebuild-core.
4. If exists, check to see if you get any additional solr connection errors in the log file of xConnect site and sitecore instance site also.

Comment: I verify the connection strings that was configured correctly

Comment: Do you see any issues in log files?

Comment: It seems some index issue, i tried with new instance, it was working as expected. plan to compare with new instance to old one, to find route cause.